# How to add local tar.gz package in conda meta.yaml requierement?

Tags: python, anaconda, conda, mamba

I have a meta.yaml recipe for conda, to build a package. (we will call it **mypackage**)

I want this package to use a local (tar.bz2) file in his requirement section (build&run) (we will call it **locapackagedep**)

Here is an **example** of what I would like to do

```
requirements:
  build:
   - setuptools
   - wheel
   - nodejs=16
   - yarn
   - jupyterlab
   - /my/path/to/locapackagedep
   - ipympl
 host:
   - python {{ python }}
 run:
   - python=3.8
   - jupyterlab
   - locapackagedep
```

I can't find any doc on it ....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe one needs to specify the package by name, and use the `-c` flag to indicate a local path that contains the build.

Something like:

```
requirements:
  build:
   - setuptools
   - wheel
   - nodejs=16
   - yarn
   - jupyterlab
   - locapackagedep
   - ipympl
 host:
   - python {{ python }}
 run:
   - python=3.8
   - jupyterlab
   - locapackagedep
```

and

```
conda build -c file://my/path/to .
```